# Select multiple distincts with group by (I think)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was wondering if someone could help me with this.  Here is a sample set of my data:

```
FirstName   LastName   Department  Comment       DateWorked
Bob         Smith      Sleeves                  2017-01-01
Jim         Bo         Sleeves                  2017-01-01
Janet       Moore      Lids        No Show      2017-01-01
Jon         Bob        Lids                     2017-01-01

Bob         Smith      Mugs                     2017-01-02

Bob         Smith      Sleeves                  2017-01-03
Jim         Bo         Sleeves                  2017-01-03
Janet       Moore      Lids                     2017-01-03
Jon         Bob        Lids                     2017-01-03
```

It should return something like this:

```
DateWorked  Department  HeadCount
2017-01-01  Sleeves     2
2017-01-01  Lids        2
2017-01-02  Mugs        1
2017-01-03  Sleeves     2
2017-01-03  Lids        2
```

So far I've tried a few things.

This is what I want but it's not working

```
SELECT Count(Distinct(FirstName, LastName, Department, Scheduled), Notes)  FROM Employees
Where Scheduled < 20171231
and Scheduled > 20170101
Group by Scheduled, Department, FirstName, LastName, Department, Comment
```

This just gives me a number.

```
select count(*)
from
  (select count(*) CT
   from Employees
   group by Scheduled, Department) TD
```

This errors out.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT FirstName, LastName, Department) FROM Employees
```

Can anyone help? 
Thanks

Comment: Which dbms are you using? MySQL? MS SQL? PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DateWorked, Department, COUNT(*) AS HeadCount 
FROM Employees
WHERE Scheduled < 20171231 AND Scheduled > 20170101 
GROUP BY Department, DateWorked
```

Comment: Thank you!  This is pretty close. I was able to get what I needed once I expanded on the group by.

Comment: I'm sorry I must have overlooked something. Your answer looks right to me. I'll mark it as such. Sorry. And thank you.

Comment: I wrote wrong the first time, but then edited. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You would appear to want:

```
SELECT DateWorked, Department, COUNT(*) as HeadCount
FROM Employees
WHERE Scheduled < 20171231 AND Scheduled > 20170101
GROUP BY DateWorked, Department
ORDER BY DateWorked, Department;
```

The above keeps the date comparisons as you have in your query, although they seem wrong.

I would recommend writing the date comparisons as:

```
SELECT DateWorked, Department, COUNT(*) as HeadCount
FROM Employees
WHERE  Scheduled >= '2017-01-01' AND Scheduled < '2017-12-31'
GROUP BY DateWorked, Department
ORDER BY DateWorked, Department;
```

This fixes the date comparisons, to be more aligned with your desired results.

You don't specify your database.  YYYY-MM-DD is the ISO standard date format and works across most databases.

Comment: Thank you.  The second version worked. It's SSMS. Sorry.  I'm checking them now and it seems to work.